# Error: unexpected '}' in " in my code.Tried suggestions but I am still stuck

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to run some reports but keep getting the following error for this command.

Command as follows:

```
for (id in (df$ID)){
        subgroup <- df[df$ID == id,]
        render("Feedback.rmd", output_dir = filepath, output_file = paste0(id, "_CMA1_22-23", ".doc"))}
```

Error as follows:

Error: unexpected '}' in "        render("Feedback.rmd", output_dir = filepath, output_file = paste0(id, "_CMA1_22-23", ".doc"))}"

I have tried substituting '.doc' for ".doc" having read answers to other similar posts. Other posts also mentioned the else command but since i haven't got that, it's moot.

Comment: Are you maybe running only the line starting with `render` instead of the for loop?

Comment: In RStudio (if that is what you are using) you could use `source` to run the code rather than `run`.

Comment: Thanks, @tavdp - definitely running the full loop.

Comment: Thanks, @John Coleman. Tried running source and it seemed to help. Identified a missing package which once installed seems to be running the output file. New error now but a step in the right direction!